# Extjs Template if condition is not working

Tags: templates, extjs

Ext Template if condition not working

Code:

```
 tpl : new Ext.Template(
                    '<tpl if="{isCommentable} == true">{qnNum}</tpl>'

                            ),
```

The above code is not working. isCommentable is from Ext.data.Record is a boolean value.

Do you know why the if condition in template is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No brackets in if clauses. Check the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate). So that would be:

```
'<tpl if="isCommentable">{qnNum}</tpl>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tpl : new Ext.Template( '<tpl if="{isCommentable}">{qnNum}</tpl>' ),
```

Answer (score 0):

And you must use Ext.XTemplate and not Ext.Template